# mysql trigger to cancel insert action on DB

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a problem inserting into my database. I want to create a trigger before insert into a table, so that I can check if some thing wrong, and if so I want to return or skip the insert action.

Exp: it acts like a rollback in SQL

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytabletriggerexample
BEFORE INSERT
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    BEGIN
        IF New.public_service_code=Null THEN
            set New.accounting_date='';
            set New.public_service_code='1002';
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: only one active row allowed per type';
            rollback;
        END IF;                   
    END
```

Comment: I seem to recall that there isn't a very nice way to abort an insert from within MySQL.  Is there any chance you could control whether or not an insert happens from your app/business layer?

Answer (score 0):

```
Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger
```

meaning you cannot rollback in a trigger

Comment: Please support your answer from a source and mention that source